# Not receiving email notifications from pipeline runs

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am having problems receiving email notifications for a pipeline I have setup like so:

```
#!groovy
pipeline {
  agent any
  stages {
    stage('Build Prep') {
      steps {
        sh '...'
      }
    }
    stage('Build') {
      steps {
        sh '...'
      }
    }
    stage('Tests') {
      steps {
        parallel (
          "Jasmine": {
            sh '...'
          },
           "Mocha": {
            sh '...'
          }
        )
      }
    }
    stage('Deploy') {
      steps {
        sh "..."
      }
    }
  }
  post {
    success {
      emailext to:"me@me.com", subject:"SUCCESS: ${currentBuild.fullDisplayName}", body: "Yay, we passed."
    }
    failure {
      emailext to:"me@me.com", subject:"FAILURE: ${currentBuild.fullDisplayName}", body: "Boo, we failed."
    }
    unstable {
      emailext to:"me@me.com", subject:"UNSTABLE: ${currentBuild.fullDisplayName}", body: "Huh, we're unstable."
    }
    changed {
      emailext to:"me@me.com", subject:"CHANGED: ${currentBuild.fullDisplayName}", body: "Wow, our status changed!"
    }
  }
}
```

The build logs confirm an email is sent, but I dont get anything in my inbox, nothing in spam either.

I have come across this https://jenkins.io/blog/2016/07/18/pipline-notifications/

But I am unsure if I can use using the syntax I have, I don't have any nodes defined, should I?

Comment: The syntax looks fine, and your pipeline works for me. Can you try sending to another email address, maybe at a different domain? I don't know why Email-Ext doesn't have a "Test configuration" option like the regular Email plugin does, but does Configure System > Email Notification > "Test configuration by sending test e-mail" work if you use the same SMTP settings as in the "Extended E-mail Notification" config?

Comment: You do have nodes (or agents) defined — in a default Jenkins install, the master acts as a build agent, with two executors (shown in the left sidebar on the main page). If you didn't have any agents defined, your build wouldn't start.

Comment: I tried using same SMTP settings in the Email Notification area and using the test email option to a couple of different accounts, but neither received the email, didnt get any failure messages. I'm wondering if the SMTP server is swallowing them for some reason. In Default Triggers of the Extended E-mail Notification section, only 'Failure - Any' is ticked. I did however compare to a freestyle job that does email out fine, this uses the Editable Email Notification plugin and has one trigger 'Always' added. But I cant see any settings for this plugin in Configure System, e.g for SMTP settings

Comment: Is the "System Admin e-mail address" a valid email address, in Configure System? I had to set that before my SMTP server would accept mail. Otherwise, it's worth checking the SMTP server logs, or trying another server. But that's weird if email from a freestyle build is working.

Answer (score 0):

Your script works fine. I did receive the email using the above code. Please check your other settings or if you had created a rule for Jenkins emails. You can make your code look easier by adding your notifications to the Jenkins shared library. Please take a look at the below link.

https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/